# In Firefox, get href of anchor in onclick trigger

Tags: javascript, firefox, onclick, cross-browser, dom-events

With the following html:

```
<div>
   <a href='#link1' onclick='func()' >Link 1</a>
   <a href='#link2' onclick='func()' >Link 2</a>
   <a href='#link3' onclick='func()' >Link 3</a>
</div>

function func() {
   var href = ??;
   if( href.match(/#link1/) ) {
      ...
   }
}
```

in Chrome (and IE?) can use this code

```
var href = window.event.target.href;
```

but `window.event` does not exist in Firefox

If the events were attached via `addEventListener` then could have `e` as an argument,  but see no way to get the event passed to the `onclick` function when declared in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do get the event as an argument, in the onclick handler itself.  So you can do:

```
 <a href="#link1" onclick="func(event)" >Link 1</a>
```

and then you can look at the event target in `func`.

Comment: outstanding!! tested on chrome and firefox - works as advertised.  means triggers work the same way whether through html script or addEventListener functions.

Answer (score 4):

Pass in `this` to your function and then directly access the href property. `this` will refer to the element that made the call. You may also want to return false - this prevents the clicked link from navigating.

http://jsfiddle.net/qjXVy/

```
function func(elem) {
    alert(elem.href);
    return false;
}
```

```
<div>
   <a href="#link1" onclick="func(this)" >Link 1</a>
   <a href="#link2" onclick="func(this)" >Link 2</a>
   <a href="#link3" onclick="func(this)" >Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought that `this` was the window, not the anchor - or is that only when `func` is called through `addEventListener`?

Comment: Because `this` is in the onclick handler, it references the clicked element. We then pass this on to the function. `this` inside the function would refer to the window.

Comment: Thank!  cannot count the number of variations of `this` in javascript I have stumbled over!

Comment: But without `this` as an arg, there's no way - is that correct?

Comment: Possible, but that is a bad way of handling things. Scroll down to the `accessing the event object` section at this link. http://www.reloco.com.ar/mozilla/compat.html